# What web sites have recipes for a Philips Pasta Maker Avance Collection

Tags: pasta, noodles

Help! I bought a Philips Pasta Maker.

[image]

I love pasta and Asian noodles. The first time I used this machine the pasta was wonderful. Ever since, there have been problems. Mostly, the pasta is dry and in some cases, half of it has to be thrown out. I was using the recipes that came with the machine.

Searching online, I found a number of complaints from owners that the recipes that come with the machine are poor.

I always made pasta by hand and never had a problem. And I want to love this machine, but so far I am disappointed.

I am sure that this can be fixed with proper recipes for the pasta mixture. I am using a combination of semolina flour and all purpose flour (4 to 1).

Any suggestions for URLs for sites that promote recipes for this machine, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can't help.  From what I can tell, the Philips is an all-plastic pasta maker.  Those just don't work.  The plastic cannot withstand the pressures required for extruding quality pasta.  I suggest returning it and getting one with metal parts.

Comment: You may be right that this machine includes plastic, but it is not all plastic. There are many metal elements to it, and it is quite heavy. My issues in not the extrusion, it is the batter consistency, which is the failure point. Once it begins to extrude, some of the batter is fine, and the remainder is not. I think that the ingredients, and their portion sizes, are the issue. I just want to know what ingredients and portion sizes have worked for other home chefs. Otherwise, the machine appears to work as designed.

Comment: The extruder plate is plastic, which is a critical failure for this; it's never going to be not frustrating.  But, feel free to watch Alex's series on dry pasta: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Fe1NvMohds for hints

Comment: Are the recipes by weight or by volume?  (Does it call for ‘cups’ of flour?). If it’s by volume, they’re going to be unreliable, as flour compresses

Comment: The recipes are by weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with restaurant and high end home pasta extruders with more power and brass dies, extruded pasta is extremely finicky and at the mercy of local ingredients and environmental conditions.  I would begin with 25% water to flour (try all semolina first or your mixture), then adjust until you find something you are happy with.  I've seen anywhere from 20% to upper 40% water noted online.  This is something you are going to have to play with. I doubt you will find a formula online that works, simply given the nature of this type of pasta and the tools available to produce it. You note that your product changes during the process, this could very well be a result of the machine itself, simply because of the power output and the parts used for extrusion, rather than your dough formula.  On top of that, once you get a noodle you are happy with, drying correctly is another issue you will have to deal with.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is helpful, and is probably what I expected. Experimenting with the ingredients make sense, especially because the types of flour I am using may be different from that used by others.

I was hoping that there was a web site where cooks shared their experiences, but apparently that is not the case.

The concern about the material used in the dies seems to be a false demon. These are extremely hard dies, and I doubt that is making any difference. From what I have observed, it is the consistency of the batter that is the issue, well before the batter is extruded.

Answer (score 0):

Join the 'Pastafanataholics with Pastidea extruding with Philips, KitchenAid & others' group on Facebook.  Tons of recipes and advice.

Comment: Hey, can you include a link to the group in your answer?  That would make it a good answer for the question.  Welcome to SA!

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/groups/767285674024266/. I joined it, and I think it is fabulous! If you go there, make sure to download Elise Feiner's guidebook "Pastafanataholics  Extruding with Love….pdf". It's a great place to start. Thank you, Elise!